# call a ui-dialog box using javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to open (call) a ui-dialog box from a function javascript. Currently I have these two codes:

```
setTimeout(function() {
var zone = event.getTarget().getName();                  
var x = window.confirm("Do you want to continue?");                     
if (x) {
    readData();
} else {
    e.preventDefault();
}
}, 0);
```

and,

```
$( "#dialogZone" ).dialog({
autoOpen: false,
show: "blind",
hide: "blind",
modal: true,
buttons: {
    "YES": function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        readData();
    },
    Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        //avoid some info windows in #tab1
    }
}
});

$( "#openEvent" ).click(function() {
$( "#dialogZone" ).dialog( "open" );
return false;
});
});
```

Please, can I have some thing like...

```
setTimeout(function() {
   // show ui-dialogbox
}
```

Thanks in advance for your answers. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have it in your code:

```
  $( "#dialogZone" ).dialog( "open" );
```

to open dialog, so put this line in your timeouted function

Comment: Vittore, It works fine but when I click on button "Yes" anything happen... do you know how is my problem please?